# Javascript referenceError Draggabilly is not defined using requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggabilly

I'm using ElastiStack js plugin from [tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/12/elastic-stack-elastic-dragging-interaction/) with requireJS. ElastiStack is dependent on [Draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com) from Desandro and Modernizr. And since the Draggabilly js included on the tympanus website is an old version, I upgraded it to the latest version on Desandro's site (v1.2.4) that now supports requireJS.

And now using it with requireJS, I got an error of

> ReferenceError: Draggabilly is not defined

```
this.draggie = new Draggabilly( this.items[ this.current ] );
```

You may check out the [the example here](http://mincg198.5gbfree.com/elastic/) (I just hosted it on a free web hosting just for this so don't mind the php error you'll see there.)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <ul id="elasticstack" class="elasticstack">
                <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="01"/><h5>Saudade</h5></li>
                <li><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="02"/><h5>Tuqburni</h5></li>
                <li><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="03"/><h5>Retrouvailles</h5></li>
                <li><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="04"/><h5>Onsra</h5></li>
                <li><img src="img/5.jpg" alt="05"/><h5>Mamihlapinatapai</h5></li>
                <li><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="06"/><h5>Koi No Yokan</h5></li>
            </ul>
            <script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': 'js', // Place all js core dependencies.
    'paths': { // Path where this file is located
        'draggabilly' : 'draggabilly.pkgd.min',
        'modernizr'   : 'modernizr.custom',
        'elastistack' : 'elastiStack',
        'main'        : 'main',
    },
    'shim' : {
        'elastistack' : {
            deps: ['draggabilly', 'modernizr']
        }
    }
});
requirejs([
    'elastistack',
    'main'
]);
```

**MAIN.JS**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(function() {
        var asd = new ElastiStack($('#elasticstack')[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: may be you missed to load  the JS file

Comment: I checked the NET on firebug and it is loading the necessary scripts.

Comment: my firewall is blocking your example's website, can you provide a fiddle

Comment: @JSantosh - added snippets already